# Check If No Record from Database is Returned and Ask to Add Item from Submit Button?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm searching my database correctly and returning the records that I have when I click my search button. I'm having a bit of a problem trying to add code to my submit button functionality. If I can't find a record in my DB, I want to just return text on the page like "Record Not Found" and display button options to add a record or cancel. I have the add record and cancel functionalities. I'm just stuck on my submit button displaying if I i cant find a record and if i can't display the buttons for add or cancel. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank You.

Here is my Controller:

```
public ActionResult TakeInventory(int? AssetNum, string owners)
        {
            var records = from s in db.Assets select s;
            if (AssetNum != 0)
            {
                records = records.Where(c => c.AssetKey == AssetNum);
            }

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(owners))
            {
                records = records.Where(x => x.InventoryOwner.Equals(owners));
            }else
            {
                return View(records);
            }
            return View(records);
```

Here is my View:

```
@model IEnumerable<CTS_Inventory.Models.Asset>
@using (Html.BeginForm("TakeInventory","InventoryManagement",FormMethod.Get))
{
    <p>
         Item: @Html.TextBox("AssetNum", "Enter An Asset Tag" )
        Inventory Owner: @Html.TextBox("owners", "Enter Owner") 
        <input type="submit" value="Search" />
    </p>
}
```

Comment: Where are you displaying existing records in that view? Why not just ad an `@if (Model.Any()) { // display records } else { // display message/buttons }`

Comment: Thanks, just did it and it worked. Also thanks for the help on my other question from a couple of days ago.